# How to get the bars on a bar chart to float directly downward, but only when scrolling to that element?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using D3 to create a bar chart that looks like this:

[image]

Currently, the bars are floating in on an angle ***from the top left corner*** (because of the D3 coordinate system).  I would like the bars to float ***directly downward***, but ***only when the user scrolls to that part of the page*** (note: the page is quite lenghty and it would take a few minutes for the user to scroll to that element).

Here is my code:

```
    let data = [
{"color": "Blue", "plotValue": 11},
{"color": "Red", "plotValue": 20},
{"color": "Orange", "plotValue": 21},
{"color": "Purple", "plotValue": 30},
{"color": "Green", "plotValue": 35},
{"color": "Violet", "plotValue": 40},
               ]


        vis.margin = {top: 70, right: 90, bottom: 90, left: 80};
        vis.width = 800 - vis.margin.left - vis.margin.right;

        // initialize the drawing area
        vis.svg = d3.select('#' + vis.parentElement).append('svg')
            .attr('width', vis.width + vis.margin.left + vis.margin.right)
            .attr('height', vis.height + vis.margin.top + vis.margin.bottom)
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', `translate (${vis.margin.left}, ${vis.margin.top})`);


        // scales and axes
        vis.xScale = d3.scaleBand()
            .range( [ 0, vis.width ] )
            .padding(0.4);

        vis.yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range( [ vis.height, 0 ] );

        vis.xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
            .scale(vis.xScale);

        vis.yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
            .scale(vis.yScale);

        // add chart title
        vis.svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'title bar-chart-title')
            .append('text')
            .text(vis.chartTitle)
            .attr('transform', `translate(${vis.width / 2 + 45}, -50)`)
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');

        // tooltip
        vis.tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
            .attr('class', 'tooltip')
            .attr('id', 'barChartTooltip');


        // create the axis groups
        vis.xAxisGroup = vis.svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'x-axis axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + vis.height + ')');

        vis.yAxisGroup = vis.svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'y-axis axis');



        let vis = this;

        // update the domains
        vis.xScale.domain(vis.data.map(function (d) { return d.color; }));
        vis.yScale.domain( [ 0, 100 ] );

        // draw the bars
        vis.bars = vis.svg.selectAll('.bar')
            .data(vis.data)

        vis.bars.exit().remove();

        vis.bars
            .enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'bar')
            .on('mouseover', function(event, d) {
                d3.select(this)
                    .attr('stroke-width', '2px')
                    .attr('stroke', 'grey')
                    .attr('fill', 'blue')

                vis.tooltip
                    .style('opacity', 1)
                    .style('left', event.pageX + 20 + 'px')
                    .style('top', event.pageY + 'px')
                    .html(`
                    <div style='border: thin solid grey; border-radius: 5px; background: lightgrey; padding: 20px'>
                    <h3>${d.color}</h3>
                    <h4> ${100- d.plotValue.toLocaleString()}% decline </h4>
                    </div>
                                        
                    `)

            })
            .on('mouseout', function(event, d) {
                d3.select(this)
                    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
                    .attr('stroke', '#456983')
                    .attr('fill', function(d) {
                        return 'red'
                    })

                vis.tooltip
                    .style('opacity', 0)
                    .style('left', 0)
                    .style('top', 0)
                    .html(``);

            })
            .merge(vis.bars)
            .transition()
            .duration(1200)
            .attr('x', d => vis.xScale(d.color) )
            .attr('y', d => vis.yScale(d.plotValue) )
            .attr('width', vis.xScale.bandwidth() )
            .attr('height', function(d) { return vis.height - vis.yScale(d.plotValue); })
            .attr('fill', 'red')
//            .attr('stroke', 'grey');


        // add the axes
        vis.xAxisGroup
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style('font-size', '15px')
            .style('color', 'blue')
            .call(d3.axisBottom((vis.xScale)))
            .selectAll('text')
            .attr('y', 30)
            .attr('x', -35)
            .attr('dy', '.35em')
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(-30)')
        ;

        vis.yAxisGroup
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style('font-size', '15px')
            .style('color', 'blue')
            .call(d3.axisLeft(vis.yScale));

        vis.text = vis.svg.selectAll('.text')
            .data(vis.data)

        vis.text
            .enter()
            .append('text')
            .attr('class', 'text')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('x', d => vis.xScale(d.color) + 27)
            .attr('y', d => vis.yScale(d.plotValue) - 10)
            .text( function (d) {
                return '-' + (100 - d.plotValue) + '%';
            })
```

How would I amend my code to get the bars to float directly downward, and only triggered when the user scrolls to that part of the page?

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such a thing like *D3 coordinate system*, that's just the **SVG** coordinate system: `0,0` is the top left corner.

For fixing your issue you just need to set the `x`, `y` and `width` attributes when the bars enter, and then change the `y` and `height` attributes on the transition. I believe showing the bars going *up* is way better for the user, but showing them coming from the top is trivial (just change the original `y` position):

```js
const vis = {};

vis.data = [{
    "color": "Blue",
    "plotValue": 11
  },
  {
    "color": "Red",
    "plotValue": 20
  },
  {
    "color": "Orange",
    "plotValue": 21
  },
  {
    "color": "Purple",
    "plotValue": 30
  },
  {
    "color": "Green",
    "plotValue": 35
  },
  {
    "color": "Violet",
    "plotValue": 40
  },
];


vis.margin = {
  top: 70,
  right: 90,
  bottom: 90,
  left: 80
};
vis.width = 800 - vis.margin.left - vis.margin.right;
vis.height = 400 - vis.margin.left - vis.margin.right;

// initialize the drawing area
vis.svg = d3.select("body").append('svg')
  .attr('width', vis.width + vis.margin.left + vis.margin.right)
  .attr('height', vis.height + vis.margin.top + vis.margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate (${vis.margin.left}, ${vis.margin.top})`);


// scales and axes
vis.xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, vis.width])
  .padding(0.4);

vis.yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([vis.height, 0]);

vis.xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(vis.xScale);

vis.yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(vis.yScale);

// add chart title
vis.svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'title bar-chart-title')
  .append('text')
  .text(vis.chartTitle)
  .attr('transform', `translate(${vis.width / 2 + 45}, -50)`)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');

// tooltip
vis.tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
  .attr('class', 'tooltip')
  .attr('id', 'barChartTooltip');


// create the axis groups
vis.xAxisGroup = vis.svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x-axis axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + vis.height + ')');

vis.yAxisGroup = vis.svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y-axis axis');

// update the domains
vis.xScale.domain(vis.data.map(function(d) {
  return d.color;
}));
vis.yScale.domain([0, 100]);

// draw the bars
vis.bars = vis.svg.selectAll('.bar')
  .data(vis.data)

vis.bars.exit().remove();

vis.bars
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'bar')
  .attr('x', d => vis.xScale(d.color))
  .attr('y', d => vis.yScale(0))
  .attr('width', vis.xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", 0)
  .on('mouseover', function(event, d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr('stroke-width', '2px')
      .attr('stroke', 'grey')
      .attr('fill', 'blue')

    vis.tooltip
      .style('opacity', 1)
      .style('left', event.pageX + 20 + 'px')
      .style('top', event.pageY + 'px')
      .html(`
                    <div style='border: thin solid grey; border-radius: 5px; background: lightgrey; padding: 20px'>
                    <h3>${d.color}</h3>
                    <h4> ${100- d.plotValue.toLocaleString()}% decline </h4>
                    </div>
                                        
                    `)

  })
  .on('mouseout', function(event, d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr('stroke-width', 1)
      .attr('stroke', '#456983')
      .attr('fill', function(d) {
        return 'red'
      })

    vis.tooltip
      .style('opacity', 0)
      .style('left', 0)
      .style('top', 0)
      .html(``);

  })
  .merge(vis.bars)
  .transition()
  .duration(1200)
  .attr('y', d => vis.yScale(d.plotValue))
  .attr('height', function(d) {
    return vis.height - vis.yScale(d.plotValue);
  })
  .attr('fill', 'red')
//            .attr('stroke', 'grey');


// add the axes
vis.xAxisGroup
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .style('font-size', '15px')
  .style('color', 'blue')
  .call(d3.axisBottom((vis.xScale)))
  .selectAll('text')
  .attr('y', 30)
  .attr('x', -35)
  .attr('dy', '.35em')
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(-30)');

vis.yAxisGroup
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .style('font-size', '15px')
  .style('color', 'blue')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(vis.yScale));

vis.text = vis.svg.selectAll('.text')
  .data(vis.data)

vis.text
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('class', 'text')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('x', d => vis.xScale(d.color) + 27)
  .attr('y', d => vis.yScale(d.plotValue) - 10)
  .text(function(d) {
    return '-' + (100 - d.plotValue) + '%';
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

Regarding doing the animation only when the user gets to the SVG, thats a completely **different** question, please keep just 1 issue per question here at SO. Thus, feel free to post another question for that separate issue (you don't need to use the [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js) tag in that new question).

Comment: Thank you, @Gerardo.  To get the bars to "float up", can you tell me what you mean by "original y position"?

Comment: Looks like I just needed to make it:  `.attr('y', d => vis.yScale(vis.height))`.

Comment: @equanimity Yes, that's it. Also, if I understand what you mean by float up, keep the height the same and transition just the `y` attribute. For the separate question I suggest you to have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API. That's what I always use in my codes.